# How to disable application restart after deleting a directory In ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, directory, data-caching

After deleting a directory in asp.net  the application will restart and I will lose all my session and the cache will clear.
So  I found the following solution; I Put the following code in the `Application_Start` of `Global.asax` to disable disable application pool recycling, but sometimes it doesn't work. Why?

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
        object o = p.GetValue(null, null);
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo f = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
        object monitor = f.GetValue(o);
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo m = monitor.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        m.Invoke(monitor, new object[] { });
```

Comment: There are many other reasons for the application pool to recycle, some of which can't be disabled. The correct solution would really be to make your application work well with recycles instead of attempting to disable them.

Comment: The right solution is not to delete directories under the application root.

Comment: but this code often work correctly.

Comment: @shiva You may can prevent it **sometimes**, but you **can't** prevent it **always**. You have to live with this.

Comment: finally I found the solution .  :)   
Read This Article . [Prevent app restarts and site downtime when deploying files ](http://beweb.pbworks.com/w/page/30073098/Prevent%20app%20restarts%20and%20site%20downtime%20when%20deploying%20files)

Comment: Good for you. It's still not possible, under no circumstances. It WILL eventually recycle. How about fixing the cause, instead of trying to work around the symptoms?

Comment: tnx for your help . my problem solved and After Deleting a directory  cache will not clear .

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** prevent the Application Pool Recycling, and doing so is the wrong way to achieve things anyway.

Instead you should not delete any files or directories within your application directory. For temporary data you should use the temp directory, for persistent data you should store it in a separate location.

Also if you care about your sessions and cache to be persisted after a application pool recycle, you should additionally store it in a persistent data storage and reload it.